# Need a Grid height 90vh but the row take random height

Tags: css, css-grid, viewport-units

I have a div that must have height:90vh
Inside there's a grid with 4 rows, and its content can grow in height depending on the content I received.
In my web if I delete the 90vh property, the height of the row takes the height of its content.

This is for AMP mobile format, keep this in mind.

Thank you :)
CSS beginner

```css
.bg-img-vodItem {
  background: rgba(45, 45, 45, 1);
}

.first-look {
  height: 90vh;
}

.content-1200-center {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.vodItemHead {
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.vodItemHeadT {
  height: 20%;
  width: 700px;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.vodItemHeadT h1 {
  font-size: 8vmin;
  font-weight: 800;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3% 0;
}

.whiteColor {
  color: #fff;
}

.vodItemHeadSubT {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.vodItemHeadSubT>section {
  padding: 0;
}

div.container {
  max-width: 700px;
}

.container,
.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

div>p {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.vodItemHeadLogo {
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.justify-left-im {
  justify-content: center;
}

.grid-auto-fit {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
}

.img-max-width {
  margin-left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.vodItemHeadBtn {
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 600px;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 4;
  text-align: center;
}

.vodItem-btn-full {
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.btn-white {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}

.fa-chevron-circle-right {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-img-vodItem first-look">
  <div class="vodItemHead content-1200-center">
    <div class="vodItemHeadT ">
      <h1 class="whiteColor">Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="headerTvShow" class="vodItemHeadSubT  whiteColor">
      <section class="section-white">
        <div class="container">
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <div class="vodItemHeadLogo">
      <div class="justify-left-im d-lg-none d-xl-block grid-auto-fit img-percent-container">
        <div class="grid-elem-auto-fit img-percent-content-home img-max-width">
          <div class="img-percent-logo-50 fullLeft-1">
            <amp-img class="contain" alt="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/110x80/000/fff" width="110" height="80" layout="fixed">
            </amp-img>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vodItemHeadBtn">
      <a href="#best_content">
        <button class="vodItem-btn-full btn-white ">Button <span class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right margin-icon-left"></span></button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want each row takes the height of its content, but for example if it's a long text, the button don't go outside down the principal div.

Comment: are you looking for : `.bg-img-vodItem {
  background: rgba(45, 45, 45, 1);
  overflow:auto
}` ? it will allow the element to scroll instead content overflowing

Answer (score 0):

You can try `min-height`

```
.first-look {
  min-height: 90vh;
}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  max-height: 90vh;  instead of height:90vh;